# How can I override `toJson` of an object which inherits Map or List in Dart

Tags: json, dart, flutter

Let say I have an object that extend a List

```dart
Class MyClass extend List<int>
```

```dart
    test('json encoding', () {
      final Map<String, dynamic> m = <String, dynamic> {
        "a": "b",
        "c": [MyClass()],
      };
      expect(json.encode(m), '{"a":"b","c":"00"}'); 
    });
```

I got this failed test

```
ERROR: Expected: '{"a":"b","c":["00"]}'
  Actual: '{"a":"b","c":[[0,0]]}'
   Which: is different.
          Expected: ... :"b","c":["00"]}
            Actual: ... :"b","c":[[0,0]]}
                                  ^
           Differ at offset 14
```

My question is that how can I override the `toJson` (or similar) to make this test pass?

Comment: You have created MyClass to be a list of integers. Hence it is giving the value as `[0,0]` which is an int array. I dont see anything wrong here.

Comment: To quote my own question "My question is that how can I **override** the toJson (or similar) to make this test pass?"

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it is in `dart:conversion` source code (as of 2.2.1 https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/add5a27120b84f37d234608df716c3ac87fb4386/sdk/lib/convert/json.dart#L670) that there's no way we can do this. I have submitted a Git issue and propose a solution https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36365#issuecomment-477450701